# Lazarus FileAssociation: File type icon disappears when file is opened in my Pascal program

Tags: icons, pascal, lazarus, freepascal, file-association

I've got the following problem: For my Free Pascal project I set up FileAssociation (https://github.com/lainz/FileAssociation / https://wiki.freepascal.org/FileAssociation) with my program's icon as the icon for the file type that is supposed to be opened in my program. And it does work - the file association is done at every start of the program (in the FormCreate procedure) and the respective files get the intended icon. But every time I actually open a file with my program its icon disappears and only reappears when the program is closed and restarted.

My file type is `.planez` which isn't used by any other program (at least on my computer).

How can I set a persistent file type icon which never disappears?

Comment: Normally your setup utility makes file associations.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand What do you mean with "setup utility"?  (sorry, I'm quite new to Lazarus/Pascal)

Comment: Setup utility = Installation program = setup.exe; the program that installs your software on a computer. You know, these things that back in the days were made in InstallShield, had a blue-black gradient background and large white shadowed text in the upper-left corner. The user clicks "Next", "Next", "Next", and "Finish".

Comment: What do you mean with *the file association is done at every start of the program*? What is the file extension of your files? Could there be a collision with another programs file extensions?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Oh, I've never used such installation stuff (though I'm quite interested in it).

Comment: @TomBrunberg My file type is .planez and the file association stuff is included in the FormCreate procedure. I'm pretty sure there's no other program using .planez (at least on my PC).

Comment: But why do you register it on every start of your program? Does your program start if you double click on a file of yours in File Explorer?

Comment: Looking at the code you refer to in `https://wiki.freepascal.org/FileAssociation` I did not download it, so I don't know whether it actually writes the registration to the The Registry. If you run both codes (also the `Button1.Click()` procedure) on startup, your problem of the disappearing icon can be a result of the code line: `assoc.ClearIconCache; //<<-- rebuild icons`. The "Another way of registering ..." looks more like what I have done successfully in the past.

Comment: I just moved the code from the ButtonClick procedure to the FormCreate procedure as I don't want to force the user to click a button (I want the FileAssociation to happen automatically). I don't really know how to use the Registry so I avoided that other way.

Comment: global fileassociation from an application might require elevation?

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort What's elevation? 

Comment: @Pixelcode: Administrative privileges. Google "UAC prompt" and you'll recognize it.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Ah, thanks. Somewhere I read that administrative privileges are only needed for stuff like registering something for all users, not just for the current one. And since the FileAssociation actually works more or less, I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: You did not answer this question I asked earlier: **Does your program start if you double click on a file of yours in File Explorer?** That is a fundamental feature of associating file types with programs.

Comment: Yes, the program starts and is able to handle the file properly.